# How to find the area of a square inside a semicircle using only the radius?

Tags: geometry, circles

Provided with only the radius of the semicircle (10 cm) and the knowledge that the corners of the square touch the semicircle, how can one find the area of this square?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Hint:  Draw a radius to one of the corners.  Legs are then $s$ and $\frac s2$.

Comment: So s^2 + (s/2)^2 = 100...

Comment: Exactly. That's all you need.

Comment: Not at all.  These things are always clear once you see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the vertices lying on the boundary of the semicircle with it's center.

Now the hypotenuse of the the 2 right triangles formed will be radius to the circle and it's length is $\frac{a}{2}\sqrt5$ (Where a is the length of the square). So we can say

$$r=\frac{a}{2}\sqrt5 \to a=2 \frac{r}{\sqrt5}$$

Hence the area is:

$$A= a^2= \frac{4r^2}{5}
= {400 \over 5}=80\,\,\,cm^{2}$$

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

$$r^2=h^2+(h/2)^2$$
$$r^2=\frac{5}{4}h^2$$
so
$$h^2=\frac{4}{5}r^2=Area$$

[image]